# Binding Problem

Tags: wpf, data-binding

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Height="37"
                   Margin="8,17,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="20"
                   Text="{Binding Contact.Name,
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**C#** Code behind **XAML**

```
public partial class Conversation : Window
{

    private Friend _Contact;
    public Friend Contact
    {
        get
        {
            return _Contact;
        }
        set
        {
            _Contact = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( "Contact" );
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged ( string propName )
    {
        if ( this . PropertyChanged != null )
            this . PropertyChanged (
                this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propName ) );
    }

    #endregion


    public Conversation ( Friend _Friend )
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );

        Contact = _Friend;
    }

    .
    .
    .

}
```

**C#** Friend Class

```
public class Friend : Person
{

    .
    .
    .

}
```

**C#** Person Class

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{       

    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( "Name" );
        }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged ( string propName )
        {
                if ( this . PropertyChanged != null )
                this . PropertyChanged ( this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propName ) );
        }

    #endregion


    .
    .
    .


}
```

**My Question :** Why Binding Doesn't Work ?

Comment: Since your question does not demonstrate much effort on your side, if bindings don't work you should at the very least provide the binding errors which are produced, if you do not know how to debug bindings you should not ask questions why it does not work but look for ways [how to do that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx). Further you still do not seem to get a lot of basics which would would understand if you had read [introductory material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact needs to be a property rather than a field.

Also, you need to change the binding so that the source is the window class.

Comment: You mean that public Friend Contact { get; set; } ? If "YES" Then "Not Working"

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working a little more? I just saw that you were trying to bind to a field and assumed that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As wangberger stated, contact must be a property.

As wangberger implied, you did not set the DataContext of the binding target (TextBlock control) or any of its ancestors (e.g. the window) to the binding source (in your case the window itself).

Also, please read Microsoft's .NET Guidelines regarding naming conventions.

P.S. Setter should only raise PropertyChanged if value != _name;